# Call HTTPS web service from android device with header to validate

Tags: android, rest, https

I want to call HTTPs web service from Android device.which contain header for validate data on server.i don't know how to call https web service writen in java.If any one explain the steps that could be help me.Thanl you !

Answer (score 0):

Please check this method:

```
private static Header[] headers;
private String executeRequest(Httpget request)
        throws SocketTimeoutException {
    String responce = null;

    try {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
        // established.
        int timeoutConnection = 120000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 120000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(request);
        // Obtain and Set Headers when login
        headers = null;
        headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        responce = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responce;

}

Header previousHeader;

// used to add headers manually that we got from the response but now it is
// done automatically
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private HttpUriRequest addHeaders(HttpUriRequest request) {
    for (int i = 0; headers != null && i < headers.length; i++) {

            request.setHeader(headers[i].getName(), headers[i].getValue());

    }
    // request.addHeader("Content-Length", "");
    return request;

}
```